# Nodemailer streaming a file attachment

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send a file that is triggered when a get request is made. I believe the contents of the file is res.body of the get request. Looking at the nodemailer docs, I see that content of the file can be specified.

```
request.get({ 
      url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id='+posting.driveID+'&exportFormat=xlsx', 
      encoding: null,  // Force Request to return the data as Buffer
      headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+access_token
      }
      }, function done (err, res) {
        console.log(res.body);
        var mailOptions={
          from : "<>",
          to : "<>",
          subject : "new download",
          generateTextFromHTML : true,
          html : "<h2>Download "+posting.title+"</h2>",
          attachments: [{
                filename: "test.xlsx",
                content: res.body
          }]
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, resp){
          if(error) {
          }
          else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + resp.message);
          }
          transporter.close();
        });
```

When res.body is logged I see that it exists. The email is sent and I receive it in my inbox. But there is no attachment to the email -- it is just a standard text email. How can I get nodemailer to send my attactment?

Comment: in res.body what kind of data you are getting

Comment: The log of res.body looks like this: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 e1 46 27 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 78 6c 2f 77 6f 72 6b 73 68 65 65 74 73 2f 73 68 65 65 74 2e ... >

Comment: I tried using the example from the nodemailer docs:

{ filename: 'text1.txt',
  content: 'hello world!'
} but I also receive an email with no attachments. It seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was looking at the documentation for nodemailer 2.0.0 when I am using 0.7.1. Syntax is a little different.

0.7.1:
{ fileName: "test.xlsx",
contents: res.body }

2.0.0:
{ filename: "test.xlsx",
content: res.body }

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna specify the content type as well. The best I could find for .xlsx was this:

```
  {
    fileName: 'myFile.xlsx',
    content: req.body,
    contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' 
  }
```